# Uniswap V3 multihop swap exactInput() reverts

Tags: uniswap, swaps, arbitrum

I try a multihop swap from GBP to CHF. Doing exactOutput works perfect. However, exactInput ends in a revert "Fail, with Error 'ST'":

```
const route = new Route([GBPUSDPool, USDEURPool, EURCHFPool], tokenGBP, tokenCHF);
const path = encodeRouteToPath(route, false);

var quotedAmountMaximum;
try {
  quotedAmountMaximum = await quoterContract.methods.quoteExactInput(path, 200000).call();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
console.log("quotedAmountMaximum:",quotedAmountMaximum);
const inputCurrency = new Contract(IERC20.abi, tokenAddress_gbp);
await inputCurrency.methods.approve(swapRouter._address, 200000).send({from: owner, gas: 1000000});
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20
try {
  const swap = await swapRouter.methods.exactInput([path,
                                              owner, 
                                              deadline,
                                              200000, 
                                              0]).send({from: owner, gas: 1000000});
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

This code reverts with "Fail with Error 'ST", which means failed in the safeTransfer() of the SwapRouter.

Here is an example (failed) transaction:

https://testnet.arbiscan.io/tx/0x1b4e43a7bc1f37c4c819252862ad9ca0249aba6afe969327998bb9bd6d5d609c

I do the same with `exactOutput()` and it works fine. Moreover, I can't debug those transactions in Tenderly.There, they cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

I increase the gas from 1'000'000 to 1'500'000 and it works now.